# Почему функция undefined в ReFlux в react native?

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет, не могу понять почему функция undefined но при этом она вызывается....
datastore:

```
onLoadUser: function (user) {
    Api.loadUser(user)
      .then((user) => alert(Actions.loadUser.completed(user))) <===== undefined
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.error));
},
onLoadUserCompleted: function (user) {
    console.log(user); <===== в консоль выводится
},
```

Comment: что именно _undefined_?

Answer (score 1):

`alert` выводит *undefined*, потому что функция *Actions.loadUser.completed* **ничего не возвращает**.

Но так как при этом, сама функция есть - она выполняется.